# Can't send receive e-mails using home wifi

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use my work laptop at home , work late most of the time.
Outlook is set up and works fine at work , via network and Wifi.
but when I get home , using  my home wifi , I'm not able to send or receive e-mails.
I can log in, I see all contacts and previous e-mails but I can not send or receive. It gives me an error saying it can't connect to my work server.  Any ideas ??

Comment: Is your mail server hosted locally at work?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your mail is hosted locally at your workplace. Ask for your IT support to enable a Remote procedure call via HTTP on the company Exchange Server. You can find more information in this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/manage-your-mailbox-remotely-HA001226403.aspx).